# Make the screen of my app longer than the device screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing a game app and I am a newbie to android. My requirement is that I want to place 2 copies of my background image side by side, so that my application's extends horizontally as twice the length of  the device and the user has to swipe his finger to go back and forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a [HorizontalScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html) and put another layout inside that (perhaps a RelativeLayout or LinearLayout).  A scroll view of any type can only have one child.

Place your images inside the inner layout and it should scroll horizontally if the contents are large enough.

Answer (score 0):

Create a [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) and put the images inside the scrollview. That way the user can scroll up/down and left/right across the screen if the images are too big for the screen.